# How to replace a string using input from a different text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 files, file1.txt - which has 100's of IP Address line by line and on my second file(file2.txt), I have an entry *ip_address* which need to replaced by the actual ip address from the file1. How to do it in Python.

Your help is much appreciated

Eg:

```
less File1.txt
10.10.10.1
10.10.20.1
10.20.10.10 etc
```

```
less File2.txt
[/tmp/test/ip_address]
whitelist = *
```

I am looking for my output to be like this:

```
[/tmp/test/10.10.10.1]
whitelist = *

[/tmp/test/10.10.20.1]
whitelist = *

[/tmp/test/10.20.10.10]
whitelist = *

etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
with open("File1.txt") as infile, open("File2.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:   #iterate each line
        outfile.write("[/tmp/test/{}]\n whitelist = *\n\n".format(line.strip()))   #Write content to file
```